# Cumulative sum of a pandas dataframe column without for loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df`.

There's a column `"a"`. I need to compute a column `"b"` which is a cumulative sum of "a" with an offset of 1 row.

So it's something like

```
df["b"][0] = 0

for i in len(df["a"]) - 1:
  df["b"][i + 1] = df["b"][i] + df["a"][i]
```

I am wondering if there's a built in function that will allow me to this without the for loop?

Here's an example with numbers:

```
df = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

After the above algorithm we should end up with

```
df = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [0, 1, 3, 6]}
```

Comment: Please add a sample input dataframe and expected output frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just need:

```
df["b"] = df["a"].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

print(df):

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  3
3  4  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df["b"] = df["a"].cumsum().shift(periods=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  3
3  4  6
```