# Subset cumulative sum of a pandas dataframe column without for loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is a follow up of my previous question in [Cumulative sum of a pandas dataframe column without for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661605/cumulative-sum-of-a-pandas-dataframe-column-without-for-loop).

Now, I have a pandas dataframe `df` that initially has 2 columns: `id` and `a`.
e.g., something like

```
df = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 5], 'a': [2.5, 3.5, 1.0, 1.0 2.0, 4.0, 2.3, 4.4]}
```

I want to produce

```
df = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 5], 'a': [2.5, 3.5, 1.0, 1.0 2.0, 4.0, 2.3, 4.4], 'b': [0, 2.5, 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3]}
```

So it introduces a new column `b` that has a cumulative sum for each unique `id`.
Is there a quick way to do this?

Note that unique `id` will always be in adjacent rows.

Comment: I suppose the last 2 values in 'b' should be 0.0 and 2.3?

Comment: @bzu Right. Sorry, just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby() for this, but return DataFrame instead of a single row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 5], 'a': [2.5, 3.5, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.3, 4.4]})


def cumsum(df):
    df['b'] = df['a'].shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)
    return df


df2 = df.groupby('id').apply(cumsum)
```

If the same id is in adjacent rows, you can also try this:

```
df['id_change'] = df['id'].diff().abs() > 0
df['cumsum'] = df['a'].shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)
df['base'] = df['cumsum'].where(df['id_change'], np.nan).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
df['b'] = df['cumsum'] - df['base']
```

I left all the columns on purpose so it is easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Is `groupby` needed when there's guarantee the same `id` will be located in adjacent rows?

Comment: Looks like it is not needed :) but it makes the code cleaner. I did not check for performance, but if you do some benchmarks please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) :

```
df["b"] = (
            df.groupby("id", group_keys=False)["a"]
              .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
          )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
   id    a    b
0   1  2.5  0.0
1   1  3.5  2.5
2   1  1.0  6.0
3   0  1.0  0.0
4   0  2.0  1.0
5   4  4.0  0.0
6   5  2.3  0.0
7   5  4.4  2.3
```

Comment: should there be a 1 inside the shift?

Comment: `periods` (_by default 1_) is different from `fill_value`. These are two different parameters: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html